# Variation of Permeability with DC magnetising Field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

For any Powder core, as DC magnetising field increases, the initial permeability decreases known as "permeability roll off".
For example for an MPP core- [image: DC magnetising curve of MPP core]

For MPP cores the initial permeability increase with increase in temperature.[image: Initial Permeability vs Temperature curve]

I find the two curves conflicting.

As I understand, for any particular inductor, increase in DC magnetising field is due to increase in current. If current increases the temperature should go up which should result in increase of permeability for this particular MPP core. But as per the DC bias curve, the initial permeability decreases as the DC magnegising force increases.

Please educate me on this.

I am just trying to understand how Inductors are designed. I just have a toroid Inductor through which I passed 50HZ current of different magnitude and noted the voltage drop across it. The question just popped up while I as looking at datasheets of different cores.